# Cancelling a view controller from loading if a URL cannot load - Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

When a view controller is being loaded it has to obtain a JSON file via a URL.  If the internet is down I would like it to cancel loading the view controller.  Here is the code so far and I know it is wrong in the catch, but it give you an idea of what I need to do.  So overall, should I be using a different override than viewDidLoad() since it "did" load?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

        var jsonText = ""
        if let url = URL(string: "http://thedomain.com/eventlistjson_r2.asp") {
            do {
                jsonText = try String( contentsOf: url,encoding: .utf8)
            } catch {
                // contents could not be loaded
                print(error)
                super.dismiss(animated: true)
            }
        } else {
            // the URL was bad!
            print("the URL was bad")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your view controller is meaningless without data, maybe you should consider trying to reach for data first and then decide whether to push/present `UIViewController` or not.
In that case whoever is instantiating view controller is trying to retrieve JSON first, and only in case of success instantiating and passing data to mentioned view controller.

Second option is that your view controller checks for data itself and in case none found, present user with information before dismissing itself. You can f.e. achieve that by:

1. Showing information directly in view of your view controller (then `viewDidLoad()` would be suitable place for that) and leaving user possibility to navigate back by pressing back button.
2. Presenting UIAlertController, where your view controller would dismiss itself on pressing alert confirmation button.

Anyway, loading and dismissing view controller without any feedback raises a flag of poor UX or design.

If you provide us with more detail on the logic behind and expected behavior, maybe I can try to offer better answer, but I believe that any of the approaches above would be a good start.

Comment: I think your second option is best for my situation because I would like to keep the code for that view controller in the view controller.  What I could do is overlay a screen on top of the other objects in the view controller which has the error text and a back button as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
jsonText = try String( contentsOf: url,encoding: .utf8)
```

blocks the main thread so when user clicks a button on the vc that push that vc , it' ll seem to the user that the app is not functioning , what you should do is inside that mainVC

```
// add loading 
// make the call in a background thread such as URLSession.shared or Alamofire
// then decide inside the callback whether to proceed with push/segue or stay in that mainVC
```

in addition a dismiss with

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) // not super
```